# Can't dynamically add a new tab to TabBar

Tags: flutter

I wanted to dynamically add a tab bar and remove it. I did my research and comes to the conclusion that TabController needs to be created anew in order to address the length. However, For some reason, the TabBar still retains its old value length. I did print it out at the top of Build Method, it did change so I don't know what is wronged. All the length and index is accounted for, they are all the same (except for Initialindex of course).

My widget:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  List<Tab> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: LocaleKeys.ALBUMS.tr()),
    Tab(text: LocaleKeys.PLAYLIST.tr()),
    Tab(text: LocaleKeys.song.tr()),
  ];

  List<Widget> myTabViews = [
    Container(
      child: Text("one"),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text("two"),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text("three"),
    ),
  ];

  void addNewTab({required Tab tab, required Widget widget}) {

    setState(() {
      // This order doesn't matter, still gives the same error whether
      // tabController is top or bottom. Same for setState.
      tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
      myTabs.add(tab);
      myTabViews.add(widget);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _myAppBar(),
      body: _myBody(),
    );
  }

  _myAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          addNewTab(
              tab: Tab(
                child: Text("rah")
              ),
              widget: Container(
                child: Text("test")
              ));
        },
        child: Text("presss"),
      ),
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: tabController,
        tabs: myTabs,
      ),
    );
  }

  _myBody() {
    return TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: myTabViews);
  }
```

The error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library ======== 

  The following RangeError was thrown building TabBar(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#08f08]], state:
    _TabBarState#3cdd3): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3 
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
TabBar TabBar:file:///home/lib/main.dart:129:15 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
        #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
        #1      _TabBarState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:1229:26)
        #2      new _GrowableList.generate (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:133:28)
        #3      _TabBarState.build (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:1208:38)
        #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4782:27)
        #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4665:15)
        #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
        #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [dynamic Tabs](https://aurimas-deimantas.medium.com/dynamic-tabbar-and-tabbarview-in-flutter-7f364b266aef,) it should work

Comment: Could you edit your link? It doesn't work. And I don't want to implement a new way for the tab bar. Right now, I'm just wondering why mine doesn't work after analyzing others answers.

Comment: @IcyHerrscher just remove the comma at the end

Comment: Thank you, I can see it now. Unfortunately, the method to building it is exaclty like mine. And it couldn't increase the tabs just like I do.